# Cannot create App Resources file in Android Studio 3.4.2

Tags: android-studio

In Android Studio 3.4.2, I am unable to create an app resource file as 
described in the [docs here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/add-resources#add_an_xml_resource_file).

Here is what I see when I do File|New

[image]

It is the MaterialMe starter in Google's android course https://github.com/google-developer-training/android-fundamentals-apps-v2/tree/master/MaterialMe

**Update**: The project structure of the course material appears to be messed up perhaps because it was created in an older version of AS.
I created a new project in AS 3.4.2 and copied over only the src folders and it is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Check it from `XML` in case of Android Studio 3.4.2, ensure that your project sync complete before you check the `File`->`New` menu

[image]

Comment: It does not show the same menu as you have. See my screenshot.

Comment: It is the MaterialMe starter in Google's android course https://github.com/google-developer-training/android-fundamentals-apps-v2/tree/master/MaterialMe

Comment: I think something is messed up with the course project structure